# Using the delegate function in Xcode to produce an image when the user releases their finger off of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to learn to build a simple app and i keep running into the issue of delegate.
I have two classes one which is setting up the original images for the app and allowing them to be moved around by the user. The other class is the ViewController class which is where I am writing the code for the delegation to create the other object that appears when the user releases the initial object on the app.

In the View Controller class the code I have written is: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCdM9.png)

I am trying to get it to work with the function "func endtouches" in the other class however I am unsure of how to do this.

Any help or guidance would be extremely appreciated

**edit

```
import UIKit

 protocol AppearBall {
    func addImage()
```

}

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, AppearBall{



func addImage() {
    img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "ShoeboxImageView.png")
}


var delegate: AppearBall?


@IBOutlet var img: UIImage!
@IBOutlet weak var ShoeboxImageView: DragImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ShoeboxImageView?.myDelegate = self




    func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
 super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


}
```

}
}

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post screenshots of code, and make sure your question is clear. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple pattern.

Start by creating a protocol, as you have.  (But uppercase because it's a type.)

```
protocol ImageProducer {
    func addImage()
}
```

Create the class that will use a delegate to accomplish something.

```
class TouchHandler {
    var delegate: ImageProducer?

    func endTouches() {
        guard let del = delegate else {
            print("No delegate set")
            return
        }
        print("Sending delegate request")
        del.addImage()
    }
}
```

Provide an implementation of the delegate protocol.  (This doesn't actually work because I don't have images.  So, ignore anything other than handler/delegate interaction.)

```
class Worker: ImageProducer {
    var box: UIImageView?
    let img: UIImage?

    init() {
        img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "somefile.png")
    }

    func startInteraction() {
        let handler = TouchHandler()
        handler.delegate = self
        handler.endTouches()
    }

    func addImage() {
        guard let image = img else {
            print("Image didn't get created")
            return
        }
        print("Creating image view")
        box = UIImageView(image: image)
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you put that code in a playground, you can see the activity by using `Worker().startInteraction()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i shall try this and let you know if it works.

Comment: Phillip Mills, I believe i have declared the delegate from the code above with some alterations. However I am struggling to call the function in the endTouches function of the other class, I understand this is a little low level to do however I’m really struggling to find the solution and would appreciate any help you can give. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you give some details about what's going wrong?  Error messages? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: the application runs fine the only thing is the object doesn't appear when i move the initial object that is already on the screen, i believe this is because i have not correctly called the object from the other classes in the "touchesEnd" function. The code i have for this at the minute is                                                   ''''func touchesEnd(_touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
        
        self.myDelegate?.addImage()
       
        class ViewController: UIViewController{
            let appearball = AppearBall?
            }''''

Comment: Can you paste some code into an edit of your question and show how `myDelegate` is defined and how it is set?